# Finding nearest neighbors of each coordinate

Tags: python, algorithm, clustering

I've got a list of coordinates (WGS1984 Decimal Degree) and have started work on a program that performs a DBSCAN on them to find clusters amongst them. To perform the DBSCAN's range query to determine the neighbors within a specified distance, I converted each point into ECEF using formulas from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181018072749/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51832.html). I then built a KD Tree to store them.

Is using a KD Tree the best method for this? I am having trouble traversing the tree because points that are clearly within the neighborhood of others are not being found.

Of note, I use the Haversine formula to determine if a point is to be added to a cluster or not, not the square distance between the two ECEF points.

Comment: Can you test the KD Tree with dummy data to make sure your implementation is correct?

Comment: @MarcPfister I think the KD Tree is likely implemented wrong. I've been messing with it switching between converting the lat/lon to x/y so that I can use square distance to find points, then just to check via `Haversine` before adding to a cluster. Can you use KD Trees with lat/lon without a conversion to another coordinate system?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use lat/lon. Maybe compare against `PyQuadTree` or even a geohash implementation?

Comment: @MarcPfister Well I thought it was because of the square distance calculation. If a point is (11.8845, 126.1885) [lat/lon] and I want to search within a 2km radius for neighbor points, decimal degrees does not translate directly to linear distances. So that's why I had to convert to ECEF.

Comment: You just need to find possible candidates to test so I would think you can approximate and err on overshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need the ECEF conversion and the k-d tree.

Only implement this algorithm with the Haversine distance function:

https://github.com/chrisjmccormick/dbscan

Comment: So most of that is already included, its not the DBSCAN that is the problem. The reason I would try to avoid that `rangeQuery()` implementation is because that forces the overall program to run at `O(N^2)` complexity. A BST would be faster to eliminate points that don't meet criteria.

Comment: The reason I used ECEF is because the world is a ellipsoid (of sorts). As latitude increases, the distance in km gets shorter and short away from the equator. So you must use `Haversine` to calculate distance. I am just having trouble traversing the tree is all.

Comment: @pstatix- any comments on my question - https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/30102/use-of-morton-key-to-reduce-number-of-grid-points?